# OPENROWSET to TABLE, Incorrect Syntax

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've got the following statement:

```
SELECT * 
INTO TempTable 
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=#;Database=#;UID=#;Pwd=#;',
                'exec dbo.[Report_StandardReport] 1, '2020-08-25'')
```

but I get the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
> Incorrect syntax near '2020'

If I run the below it works fine. I really can't see what's wrong. Any ideas?

```
exec dbo.[Report_StandardReport] 1, '2020-08-25'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to double-up single quotes:

```
... 'exec dbo.[Report_StandardReport] 1,''2020-08-25'';');
```